# How to iterate over array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am having array of objects through which I have to iterate and return the particular object whose isPremium property value is true `isPremium === true`, I have used `.forEach` and `.map function` to achieve the functionality, but my solution is not filtering according to condition,   below is my array and my solution, Can anyone help, thanks in advance

```
  const brands = [
           {id:1, brand_name: 'adidas', brand_trans: 'أديداس', isPremium: true, url: '/brands/adidas'},
           {id:2, brand_name: 'adidas Originals', brand_trans: 'أديداس اوريجينال', isPremium: false, url: '/brands/adidas-originals'},
           {id:4, brand_name: 'Bodyism', brand_trans: 'بودييزم', isPremium: false, url: '/brands/bodyism'},
           {id:5, brand_name: 'Columbia', brand_trans: 'كولومبيا', isPremium: false, url: '/brands/columbia'},
           {id:5, brand_name: 'Converse', brand_trans: 'كونفرس', isPremium: true, url: '/brands/converse'},
         ];
```

---

**Solution**

```
         var premiumHeader = brands.map(function(item, index) {
            for( var key in item ) {
             return item.isPremium !== false;
           }
         });

         premiumHeader;
```

---

Comment: You're looking for `.filter()` or `.find()`.

Comment: If you are wanting to filter elements, then use [.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?v=example)

Comment: Please [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+filter+array+of+objects) before posting. More on searching [here](/help/searching).

Comment: I have to iterate over an array of objects and return the objects whose isPremium value is true SLaks

Comment: change .map to .filter - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/pwEQoj for  reference

Answer (score -1):

Try the `Array.filter` function:

```
var premiumItems = brands.filter( item => item.isPremium );
```